# Reference Properties Shows Blank

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, solution-explorer

I installed both Visual Studio 2017 & 2019 everything seems to be fine, except on the Reference Properties it shows blank

[image: Blank Reference Properties]

It should show below instead of showing blank

[image: Default Properties]

Anyone had the same issue before?

Comment: would be helpful if you could provide the exact version and which type of reference this is (NuGet-package, assembly-reference, project-reference, ...).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. If I select the reference e.g System.Data it will show the details. Like on the screenshot https://paste.pics/8a9dfc7711e14e2999bbe74084e586df

Comment: So which references are not showing up?  What exact object?

Comment: All the references. Even the external libraries. I tried to reset the VS settings and even reinstalled without luck.

Comment: Note that in the first screenshot, it does not show a reference selected. The second screenshot does (System.Data). What reference did you select for the first screenshot? Obviously, if you don't select something, it won't show properties.

Comment: I have edited the question. The second screen is on my other PC where it is showing fine (the same VS versions 2017&2019 are installed as well). The first screenshot is on my new PC where I have just installed both VS 2017 & 2019 but it's showing blank properties

Comment: Does this help https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/project-properties-is-empty/719279 ?

Comment: Hi @eglease .. Thanks, I have tried that already without luck.

Comment: Looks like this is a known VS bug.  Here is a link where it says how to clear cache, maybe that will fix it.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2019-project-properties-wont-show-any-details-in/480713

Comment: The ComponentModelCache directory is inside the VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxx so removing the cache folder did not help. My old PC has version 15.9.38 which is working fine, while the new PC has version 15.9.40, both are Community Version. Anyway, thanks guys for your help.